# android forcing localized resource selection by own decision not by device configurations

Tags: android, android-resources

in my case the application will be installed on a single device and will be used by different users to login and use the app, problem here is that the users are of different languages you can say some are of french language and some are English language so i decided to do this by putting two strings.xml files, one in "Values-fr" for french ones and one in "Values" means if the person is french then use french resources otherwise default will be English resources. as this will not work because device is single and it'll be irritating if french one have to change device language to french to see app in french and then when English user came he needs again to change the device local language to English to see app in English. so language prefrences are stored in database for each user. i just want here that the selection of localized resources i.e the selection between "Values" and "Values-fr" should be done by my decision not by android deciding on the basis of device local language. is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the locale from within the app so that the proper values are assigned and restore it when quitting. This is rather a crude solution to your problem.

This [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127121431/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/force-localize-application-on-android.html) could be useful in your quest.